# Backbone validation on existing tutorial

Tags: javascript, jquery, backbone.js

I did the following tutorial by Thomas Davis and I have decided to add some validation to the age field. I have tried to edit the Model as follows but no success:

```
var User = Backbone.Model.extend({
    validate: function(attr, error) {
        if(attr.age < 18) {
            console.log(error);
            return error;
        }
    },
    checkValidation: function(){
        if (validate) {
           console.log('validation successful');
        } else {
            urlRoot: '/users'
        }
    }
});
```

Full code [here](http://jsfiddle.net/FGDk4/1/)

Tutorial: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=FZSjvWtUxYk

Comment: Can you describe what you mean by "no success"?

Comment: sure, I need to validate the age input field (see full code) and I would like to console.log the error without letting the form go to: (urlRoot: '/users') until validated.

Comment: I was thinking about a conditional statement to check if the validation is successful than redirect to the '/users'

Answer (score 0):

Your validate method will be called automatically when you call set or save on a model and will prevent the save method from continuing if you return anything, like you are. If you want to check the validation outside of set/save you can just call '[this.isValid()](http://backbonejs.org/#Model-isValid)'.

There are two problems with your checkValidation method :

```
checkValidation: function(){
        if (validate) { //where is this validate variable coming from?
           console.log('validation successful');
        } else {
            urlRoot: '/users' //not doing anything, don't use : syntax outside of an object
        }
    }
```

If you want a method to do this, try this :

```
checkValidation: function(){
        if (this.isValid()) {
           console.log('validation successful');
        } else {
            this.urlRoot = '/users' //must specify this, use =
        }
    }
```

In either case I would read up on the validate method : http://backbonejs.org/#Model-validate or look at the internals of how it works : http://backbonejs.org/docs/backbone.html#section-68